# Get and display values from metabox on custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I have some metaboxes that work fine--I can input values, and they are saved. However, they will not display on my main "feed" page in WordPress! If anyone has any idea of what I'm doing wrong, please help!

I am using the following code in the while "have_posts" loop of the index.php file in my theme:

```
$intro = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'post_intro', true);
        echo $intro;
```

I've also tried adding this to the functions.php file of my theme, but no dice.

Comment: the syntax is correct, so its either `get_the_ID()` is not returning the post id or you have the key incorrect. Make sure you are calling `the_post`

Comment: `get_the_ID()` only works inside the loop. So in case you're using this outside the loop you can get the id of the current post like this:  

`global $post;  
echo $post->ID;`

Comment: OK-- is it correct that that code should go in the index.php file of my theme, and in the   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();   loop?